# Whose View is not on hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting this error from swift and I am unsure why there is only 1 view controller that actually has this occurring the error is whose view in not on the hierarchy. My question is why would this occur for one of the view controllers presented from this primary viewcontroller button but not the other view controller linked from this primaryview controller? Is there something that could cause this to occur specifically. I am trying to present this modally and it is being called programmatically so that I can pass data objects.

For me it just seems very strange that this would occur for one viewcontroller presented from this viewcontroller but not the other. The only thing I did which I didn't think would effect this was duplicating the primary viewcontroller but again why would one work but not the other? The problem is specifically happening with iOS.

Answer (score -1):

Should have checked the buttons to make sure they were linked correctly. I realized after reading a few of the same questions that I should check the button selectors under the view controller references tab to see what was linked to what. I had 2 actions doing 2 different things for 1 button by accident I must have miss clicked the control drag function.